# Is there any museum in Europe about Olympics?

Tags: europe, museums, olympics

I'm looking for a museum in Europe that shows the history of modern Olympics. I would prefer a museum in Central Europe, but other parts in Europe are also okay.

Comment: http://www.olympic.org/content/museum/the-olympic-museum/

Comment: It's closed until the end of 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have four options, although you may need to wait for a couple of them...

1. [The Olympic Museum in Lausanne, Switzerland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_Museum) houses permanent and temporary exhibits relating to sport and the Olympic movement.   However it's closed for renovations until the end of next year.
2. [The Norwegian Olympic Museum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_Olympic_Museum) in Hakon's Hall in Lillehammer, was officially opened by King Harald V and Queen Sonja on November 27, 1997. It is the only museum in northern Europe that presents the entire history of the Olympic Games.
3. [The Thessaloniki Olympic Museum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sports_Museum_of_Thessaloniki) used to be just a Sports Museum, but was moved to a new building in 2004 during the Olympic Games year in Athens, and was redesignated as the Olympic Museum.
4. In 2014, [an Olympic Museum will open in London, England](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-17176884).  Interactive exhibits will gather together London 2012 memories, show how the venues were built, and seek to inspire future generations.

Comment: Note that the London Olympic Museum [never opened](http://www.insidethegames.biz/articles/1015224/exclusive-london-olympic-museum-plans-shelved), apparently due to lack of funds.